# How can I fix the java lang errorjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/markers/KMappedMarker?

Tags: java, kotlin, gson, okhttp

I have a problem, when connecting to the pokeapi api using java in eclipse, I am using gson and okhttp3, but when executing the method that makes the http request I get a java lang error that says that kotlin dependencies are missing, I have installed the kotlin jar and imported it, however I still get the error
This is the code

```
package pokemon;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import kotlin.*;
ublic class Pokemon  {
    /*Esto guarda en una variable local de tipo String llamado url
    la e indica que se esta utilizando SQL Server en la misma máquina 
    en la que se está ejecutando el programa, en el puerto 3003, y que la base de 
    datos que se está utilizando se llama "pokemondb"
    El trusted server es para que no tire  error de certificado*/
      private static final String driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DriverJDBCVersion";
      private static final String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:3003;databaseName=pokemondb;TrustServerCertificate=True";
      private int numeroPokedex;
      private String nombre;
      private double peso;
      private double altura;
      public Pokemon(int numeroPokedex, String nombre, double peso, double altura) {//Constructor del array list
            this.numeroPokedex = numeroPokedex;
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.peso = peso;
            this.altura = altura;
        }
      
        public int getNumeroPokedex() {
        return numeroPokedex;
    }

    public void setNumeroPokedex(int numeroPokedex) {
        this.numeroPokedex = numeroPokedex;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public double getPeso() {
        return peso;
    }

    public void setPeso(double peso) {
        this.peso = peso;
    }

    public double getAltura() {
        return altura;
    }

    public void setAltura(double altura) {
        this.altura = altura;
    }
    public static class CompararPeso implements Comparator<Pokemon> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Pokemon p1, Pokemon p2) {
            return Double.compare(p2.getPeso(), p1.getPeso());
        }
    }

    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Pokemon: numeroPokedex: " + numeroPokedex + ", Nombre: " + nombre + ", Peso: " + peso + ", Altura: " + altura;
        }//para mostrar datos con el arraylist
    //jbd es una api de Java que permite establecer conexion de Java con SQl
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection con=conexion();
        Scanner escaner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean salir = false;//bandera para salir del menu
        int opcion; //Guardaremos la opcion del usuario
        do
        {
            System.out.println("-------- Menu Principal--------");
            System.out.println("1 Mostrar todos los pokemons ");
            System.out.println("2 Actualizar nombre del pokemon por su numero de la Pokedex ");
            System.out.println("3 Borrar pokemon ");
            System.out.println("4 Insertar nuevo pokemon ");
            System.out.println("5 Mostrar todos los movimientos(incluyendo MT y MO) que puede apreder un pokemon");
            System.out.println("6 Filtrar los pokemon por tipos ");
            System.out.println("7 Mostrar el número de movimientos de cada tipo ");
            System.out.println("8 Mostrar la informacion del un pokemon ");
            System.out.println("9 Mostrar los 10 pokemones más pesados ");
            System.out.println("10 Mostras los nombres de los pokemons por llamadas a la API ");
            System.out.println("11 Salir ");
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Ingrese una opcion");
            opcion=escaner.nextInt();
            switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                mostrarPokemon();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Inserte el numero de la Pokedex");
                int id=escaner.nextInt();
                System.out.println("INTRODUZCA EL NUEVO NOMBRE DEL POKEMON");
                String nombre=escaner.next();
                actualizarPokemon(id,nombre );
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Inserte el numero de la Pokedex");
                int id1=escaner.nextInt();
                borrarPokemon(id1);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("INTRODUZCA EL NOMBRE DEL NUEVO POKEMON");
                String nombre1=escaner.next();
                System.out.println("INTRODUZCA EL PESO DEL POKEMON");
                Float peso=escaner.nextFloat();
                System.out.println("INTRODUZCA LA ALTURA DEL NUEVO POKEMON");
                Float altura=escaner.nextFloat();
                insertarPokemon(nombre1, peso, altura);
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Introduce el numero de la pokedex");
                int n=escaner.nextInt();
                mostrarMovimiento(n);
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("Introduce un tipo para filtrarlo");
                String tipo=escaner.next();
                filtrarTipo(tipo);
                break;
            case 7:
                System.out.println("Introduce un tipo");
                String tipo2=escaner.next();
                filtrarMovimiento(tipo2);
                break;
            case 8:
                System.out.println("Introduce el numero de la Pokedex para mostrar");
                int n1=escaner.nextInt();
                mostrarInformacion(n1);
                break;
            case 9:
                mostrarPesados();
                break;
            case 10:
                obtenerNombrePokemon();
                break;
            case 11:
                salir=true;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }while(!salir);//mientras salir no sea verdadero
        escaner.close();
    }
        public static void mostrarPokemon() throws SQLException{
            Connection con=conexion();
            String pokedex = "SELECT NUMERO_POKEDEX,NOMBRE  FROM Pokemon";
            PreparedStatement ps =con.prepareStatement(pokedex);
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){//mientras que en la consulta de rs se obtengra una respuesta
                System.out.println(rs.getInt("NUMERO_POKEDEX")+": "+rs.getString("NOMBRE"));//imprima la consulta de rs
            }
            
            
        }
        public static String actualizarPokemon(int id, String nombre) throws SQLException{
            Connection con=conexion();
            String consulta = "Update Pokemon set NOMBRE=?  where NUMERO_POKEDEX=?";
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(consulta);
            ps.setString(1, nombre);//establece el nombre del parametro nombre
            ps.setInt(2, id);//establece el valor del parametro NUMERO_POKEDEX
            ps.executeUpdate();//para ejecutar el update
            return "El nombre del pokemon con id " + id + " ha sido actualizado a " + nombre;
        }
        public static String borrarPokemon(int id) throws SQLException{
            Connection con=conexion();
            String consulta="delete  from Pokemon where NUMERO_POKEDEX= ?";
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(consulta);
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ps.executeUpdate(); // Ejecutar la consulta de eliminación2
            return "El pokemon con numero "+id+" has sido eliminado";
        }
        public static void insertarPokemon(String nombre,double peso, double altura) throws SQLException{
            Connection con=conexion();
             String consulta = "INSERT INTO Pokemon(NOMBRE, PESO, ALTURA) VALUES (?,?,?)";
             PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(consulta);
             ps.setString(1,nombre);
             ps.setDouble(2,peso);
             ps.setDouble(3,altura);
             ps.executeUpdate();
            // Obtener el último número de la Pokédex insertado
                String n = "SELECT MAX(NUMERO_POKEDEX) AS NUMERO_POKEDEX FROM Pokemon";
                PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement(n);
                ResultSet rs = ps1.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    int numeroPokedex = rs.getInt("NUMERO_POKEDEX");
                    System.out.println("Se ha insertado el nuevo Pokémon con nombre " + nombre + " y número de la Pokédex " + numeroPokedex);
                }
               
        }
        private static void mostrarMovimiento(int n) throws SQLException{
            Connection con=conexion();
            String consulta = "SELECT p.NUMERO_POKEDEX, m.NOMBRE AS MOVIMIENTO FROM Pokemon p JOIN Pokemon_Movimiento_Forma pmf ON p.NUMERO_POKEDEX = pmf.NUMERO_POKEDEX JOIN Movimiento m ON pmf.ID_MOVIMIENTO = m.ID_MOVIMIENTO WHERE p.NUMERO_POKEDEX = ?";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(consulta);
            ps.setInt(1, n);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                String nombreMovimiento = rs.getString("MOVIMIENTO");
                System.out.println(nombreMovimiento);
            }
    }
        private static void filtrarTipo(String t) throws SQLException {
            Connection con=conexion();
            String consulta="select p.NUMERO_POKEDEX,p.NOMBRE,p.PESO,p.ALTURA,t.nombre from pokemon p join Pokemon_Tipo pt on p.NUMERO_POKEDEX=pt.NUMERO_POKEDEX join Tipo t on pt.ID_TIPO=t.ID_TIPO  where t.nombre=?;";
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(consulta);
            ps.setString(1,t);
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                int numeroPokedex = rs.getInt("NUMERO_POKEDEX");
                String nombrePokemon = rs.getString("NOMBRE");
                double peso = rs.getDouble("PESO");
                double altura = rs.getDouble("ALTURA");
                String nombreTipo = rs.getString("nombre");
                System.out.println(numeroPokedex + ": " + nombrePokemon + " - Peso: " + peso + " - Altura: " + altura + " - Tipo: " + nombreTipo);
            }
        }
        private static void filtrarMovimiento(String t) throws SQLException {
            Connection con=conexion();
            String consulta="select t.nombre, count(t.nombre) AS \"Numeros de movimiento\" from Movimiento m join Tipo t on m.ID_TIPO=t.ID_TIPO where t.nombre=? group by t.nombre";
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(consulta);
            ps.setString(1,t);
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                String nombreTipo = rs.getString("nombre");
                int numerosMovimiento = rs.getInt("Numeros de movimiento");
                System.out.println("Tipo: " + nombreTipo + " - Número de movimientos: " + numerosMovimiento);
            }
        }
        private static void mostrarInformacion(int i) throws SQLException {
            Connection con=conexion();
            String consulta="select NUMERO_POKEDEX, NOMBRE,PESO,ALTURA from Pokemon where NUMERO_POKEDEX=?";
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(consulta);
            ps.setInt(1, i);
            ArrayList<Pokemon> pokemon=new ArrayList<>();
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                pokemon.add(new Pokemon(rs.getInt("NUMERO_POKEDEX"),rs.getString("NOMBRE"),rs.getDouble("PESO"),rs.getDouble("ALTURA")));
            }
            System.out.println(pokemon);//arraylist tiene el toString implicito
        }
        private static void mostrarPesados() throws SQLException {
            Connection con=conexion();
            String consulta="select  NUMERO_POKEDEX,NOMBRE,PESO,ALTURA from Pokemon";
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(consulta);
            ArrayList<Pokemon> listaPokemon = new ArrayList<>();
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                int numeroPokedex = rs.getInt("NUMERO_POKEDEX");
                String nombre = rs.getString("NOMBRE");
                double peso = rs.getDouble("PESO");
                double altura = rs.getDouble("ALTURA");
                Pokemon pokemon = new Pokemon(numeroPokedex, nombre, peso, altura);//crea un objeto pokemon 
                listaPokemon.add(pokemon);//añade el objeto pokemon a una lista
            }
            Collections.sort(listaPokemon, new CompararPeso());
            for (int p=0; p<10;p++) {//muestra los 10 primeros mas pesados
                System.out.println(listaPokemon.get(p));
            }
        }
        private static void obtenerNombrePokemon() {//obtendra el nombre de los pokemons haciendo la llama a la pokeapi
            String url1 = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=151";//Define la URL de la API que se utilizará para obtener la información de los Pokémon.
            try {
                // Realizar la llamada a la API y obtener la respuesta como una cadena JSON
                String respuestaJson =llamadaAPI(url1);//Realiza la llamada a la API utilizando el método llamadaAPI() y obtiene la respuesta JSON como una cadena.

                // Analizar la respuesta JSON utilizando la librería GSON
                Gson gson = new Gson();// Crea una instancia de la clase Gson, que se utiliza para analizar JSON.
                JsonObject json = gson.fromJson(respuestaJson, JsonObject.class);//Analiza la respuesta JSON utilizando la instancia de Gson y convierte la cadena JSON en un objeto JsonObject.
                // Obtener el array de resultados que contiene los detalles de cada Pokémon
                JsonArray resultados = json.getAsJsonArray("resultados");//Obtiene el array de resultados de la respuesta JSON utilizando la clave "resultados".

                // Recorrer el array y obtener los nombres de los Pokémon
                for (JsonElement resultado : resultados) {//Itera sobre cada elemento del array de resultados.
                    String nombrePokemon = resultado.getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString();//Obtiene el nombre de cada Pokémon en forma de cadena.
                    System.out.println(nombrePokemon);//Imprime el nombre del pokemon
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();//Captura cualquier excepción que pueda ocurrir durante el procesamiento y la imprime en la consola mediante e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
        
        private static Connection conexion()  {
                Connection con=null;
                try {
                    Class.forName(driver);
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"sa","1Ci9z3u*Psd91Ci9z3u*Psd9");/*establece una conexión con la base de datos a través de JDBC (Java Database Connectivity), 
                    //utilizando la URL de conexión especificada.DriverManager es una clase del paquete java.sql 
                    que se encarga de cargar y registrar el controlador JDBC apropiado, y devolver una instancia de Connection 
                    que representa una conexión con la base de datos.*/
                    System.out.println("Conexión exitosa");
                    
                } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error de conexión: " + ex.getMessage());
                }
                return con;             
          }
        private static String llamadaAPI(String u) throws IOException {//Se encarga de realizar la llamada HTTP a la API y devolver la respuesta como una cadena de texto.
            OkHttpClient cliente = new OkHttpClient();/*Crea una instancia de OkHttpClient, que es una clase proporcionada por la librería OkHttp para realizar solicitudes HTTP.*/
            Request solicitud = new Request.Builder()//Crea una solicitud HTTP resquest utilidando el Resquest.Builder
                    .url(u)//En este metodo se especifica la url de la solicitud, es decir toma como parametro de entra a la url de llamadaAPI
                    .build();//Este metodo construye la solicitud de la url(es decir que.build  costruye la solicitud de .url(u)

            Response respuesta = cliente.newCall(solicitud).execute();//Envia la solicitud HTTP a la pokeapi,utilizando el cliente creado con OkHttpClient
                                                                      //y obtine la respuesta utilizando el metodo execute, esa respuesta se guardara en el objeto respuesta del tipo Response
            return   respuesta.body().string();//Devuelve el objeto respuesta como una cadena de texto  utilizando el método body().string() del objeto Response. 
                                               //Esto extrae el contenido de la respuesta HTTP como una cadena de texto.    
        }
        }
```

[Here you can see the error when executing the method that obtains the names of the pokemons through an http request to the pokeapi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5Jn2.png)

I am trying to make a method that obtains and shows the names of the 151 pokemons through the http request to the pokeapi, for this I am using gson and okhttp3, I know that the error comes from depending on okhttp3 from the kotlin libraries but, even adding the kotlin jar and importing the kotlin package, I can fix the java lang error

Comment: Seems like something is missing in the Kotlin package you're using. Try reinstalling the Kotlin?

Comment: This might be a class loader related issue since pokeapi uses its own classloader, but first try reinstalling kotlin as @acrastt said